# Remove button for shopping cart is not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, ejs

I am trying to setup a mock website that has a button to remove items from my shopping cart. The items are able to be add the cart with no issue. However, when I go into my shopping cart and click the remove button it says invalid item ID. I am using Postgresql pgadmin 4 as my database. I have four tables setup: ***cart, products, session, and users***. In my **cart table** I have the columns: user_id (integer), product_id (integer), quantity (integer), session_id (character varying), and id [PK] (integer). In my **products table** I have the columns: product_id [PK] (integer), product_name (character varying), product_description (text), price (numeric 10,2), stock_quantity (integer), category (character varying), image_path (character varying). In my **session table** I have the columns: sid [PK] (character varying), sess (json), expire (timestamp without time zone). In my **users table** I have the columns: id [PK] (integer), username (character varying), email (character varying), password (character varying), created_at (timestamp with time zone), etc..(address, city, zip, etc).
Below I will supply my ejs file called shoppingCart.ejs and my two javascript files called server.js and script.js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/68f1328681.css" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/hero.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stamps.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/notFound.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/register.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/profile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/shoppingCart.css">
    <title>Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header products">
        <a href="#" class="logo"><img class="header-logo" src="/Images/Images/logo.png" alt="">Nautical Rarities</a>
        <nav class="navbar">
          <a id="home-button" href="index">Home</a>
          <a href="stamps">Stamps</a>
          <a href="comics">Comics</a>
        </nav>
        <a href="shoppingCart" id="cart-icon"><i class="fa-sharp fa-light fa-cart-shopping fa-sm"></i></a>
        <a href="login" id="person-icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-user fa-sm"></i></a>
        <a href="#" id="bars-icon"><i class="fa-sharp fa-light fa-bars-sort fa-sm"></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          <a href="#">Events</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section>
        <h1>My Cart</h1>
        <div class="shopping-container">

          <%
            let subtotal = 0;
            cartItems.forEach(function(item) {
              subtotal += item.price * item.quantity;
            });
            let taxRate = 0.06; // Florida's state tax rate of 6%
            let taxAmount = subtotal * taxRate; // Calculate tax based on the subtotal
            let total = subtotal + taxAmount; // Calculate the final total
          %>
            <div class="left-side">
              <% cartItems.forEach(function(item) { %>
                <div class="shopping-cart-item">
                  <div class="shopping-cart-image-container">
                    <img class="product-card-image" src="<%= item.image_path %>" alt="<%= item.product_name %>" >
                  </div>
                  <div class="shopping-cart-info">
                    <p class="item-name"><%= item.product_name %></p>
                    <p class="item-quantity">Quantity: <%= item.quantity %></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="shopping-cart-total">
                    <p class="item-price">Price: $<%= item.price %></p>
                    <button class="remove" data-item-id="<%= item.id %>" onclick="removeFromCart(this)">
                      Remove
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <% subtotal += item.price * item.quantity; %>
                </div>
              <% }); %>

            </div>

            <div class="right-side">

              <div class="Summary">
                <h3>Summary</h3>
                <br>
              </div>
              <div class="subtotal-container">
                <div class="left">
                  <p>Subtotal</p>
                  <p>Est. Tax</p>
                  <br>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                  <p>Subtotal: $<%= subtotal.toFixed(2) %></p>
                  <p>Tax: $<%= taxAmount.toFixed(2) %></p>
                </div>
                
              </div>
              <div class="total">
                <p>Total</p>
                <p>$<%= total.toFixed(2) %></p>
              </div>
              <button class="check-out" onclick="redirectToCheckout()">
                Checkout 
              </button>

            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </section>
    <footer>
        <div class="fifth-container">
            <!--Footer Section-->
            <div class="social-container">
              <a href="#" class="logo-footer"><img class="logo-image" src="/Images/Images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
              <h6 class="copyright">2023 all Right Reserved</h6>
            </div>
    
            <div class="contact-us-container">
              <h1>Contact Us</h1>
              <p>P.O Box 1515</p>
              <p>Riviera Beach, Florida 33404</p>
              <br />
              <h5>Support@NauticalRarities.com</h5>
            </div>
    
            <div class="tabs-container">
              <div class="sub-container">
                <h5 class="tabs">Getting Started</h5>
                <h5 class="tabs">Information</h5>
                <h5 class="tabs">Company</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="sub-two">
                <h5 class="tabs">Products</h5>
                <h5 class="tabs">Contact</h5>
                <h5 class="tabs">About</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="subscribe-container">
              <h1>Subscribe</h1>
              <div class="subscribe-box">
                <p>Email</p>
                <!--Type Email Here Box-->
              </div>
              <div class="subscribe-button">
                <p>Subscribe</p>
                <!--Blue Subscribe button-->
              </div>
              <div class="follow-us">
                <h4 class="h-follow">Follow Us</h4>
                <div class="icons">
                  <a href="#" id="facebook-icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-2xl"></i></a>
                  <a href="#" id="twitter-icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-2xl"></i></a>
                  <a href="#" id="-icon"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-2xl"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"){
  require('dotenv').config();
}

//Importing libraries that were installed using npm
const express = require(`express`);
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const passport = require("passport");
const initializePassport = require("./passport-config");
const saltRounds = 10;
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const session = require("express-session");
const pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);

// PostgreSQL pool initialization
const pool = new Pool({
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT
});


initializePassport(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById);


app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); // line to tell Express to serve static files from the 'public' directory


app.use(flash())
app.use(session({
  store: new pgSession({
    pool: pool, // Use the existing pool
    tableName: 'session' // Use your custom table name; it defaults to 'session'
  }),
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET, 
  resave: false, // will not resave session variable if nothing changed
  saveUninitialized: true, // This will create a session even for users who are not logged in
  cookie: { secure: false } // Set to true if using HTTPS+

}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Routes Start
app.get(`/index`, (req, res) => {
    res.render(`index`)
})

app.get(`/login`, (req, res) => {
    res.render('login', { messages: { error: req.flash('error') } });
});

app.get(`/register`, (req, res) => {
    res.render(`register`)
})

app.get('/stamps', async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const result = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = $1 ORDER BY product_id', ['stamp']);
      
      // Process the products to ensure the price is correctly formatted
      const processedProducts = result.rows.map(product => {
        return {
          ...product,
          // Convert the price to a number and fix to two decimal places
          price: Number(product.price).toFixed(2)
        };
      });

      // Pass the processed products to your 'stamps' EJS template
      console.log(processedProducts);
      res.render('stamps', { products: processedProducts });
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching stamps:', error);
      res.status(500).send("Error loading stamps.");
  }
});

app.get('/comics', async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const result = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = $1 ORDER BY product_id', ['comic']);
      
      // Process the products to ensure the price is correctly formatted
      const processedProducts = result.rows.map(product => {
        return {
          ...product,
          // Convert the price to a number and fix to two decimal places
          price: Number(product.price).toFixed(2)
        };
      });

      // Pass the processed products to your 'stamps' EJS template
      console.log(processedProducts);
      res.render('comics', { products: processedProducts });
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching comics:', error);
      res.status(500).send("Error loading comics.");
  }
});

app.get(`/notFound`, (req, res) => {
    res.render(`notFound`)
})
app.get(`/profile`, (req, res) => {
  res.render(`profile`)
})
app.get(`/shoppingCart`, async (req, res) => {
  const sessionId = req.session.id; // This will be the session ID for a guest
  const userId = req.user ? req.user.id : null; // This will be the user ID if logged in
  

  try {
    let cartItems;
    if (userId) {
      // Fetch cart items for a logged-in user
      const result = await pool.query(`
        SELECT p.*, c.quantity FROM products p
        JOIN cart c ON p.product_id = c.product_id
        WHERE c.user_id = $1
      `, [userId]);
      cartItems = result.rows;
    } else {
      // Fetch cart items for a guest user
      const result = await pool.query(`
        SELECT p.*, c.quantity FROM products p
        JOIN cart c ON p.product_id = c.product_id
        WHERE c.session_id = $1
      `, [sessionId]);
      cartItems = result.rows;
    }
    
    // Render the shopping cart page with the cart items
    res.render('shoppingCart', { cartItems: cartItems });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching cart items:', error);
    res.status(500).send("Error loading the shopping cart.");
  }
});
app.get(`/guestCheckOut`, (req, res) => {
  res.render(`guestCheckOut`)
})
app.get(`/checkOut`, (req, res) => {
  res.render(`checkOut`)
})

app.get('/search', async (req, res) => {
  // Normalize the search query by removing spaces, dashes, and hash symbols
  const searchQuery = req.query.query.replace(/[-#\s]/g, '');

  try {
    // Search for the product by name, ignoring spaces, dashes, and hash symbols
    const results = await pool.query(`
      SELECT * FROM products WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(product_name, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '#', '') ILIKE $1
    `, [`%${searchQuery}%`]);

    if (results.rows.length > 0) {
      const category = results.rows[0].category;
      
      if (category === 'stamp') {
        res.redirect('/stamps');
      } else if (category === 'comic') {
        res.redirect('/comics');
      } else {
        res.redirect('/');
      }
    } else {
      res.redirect('/notFound');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error executing search query', err.stack);
    res.redirect('/notFound');
  }
});

//Routes End

// user retrieval from a PostgreSQL database 

async function getUserByEmail(email) {
  try {
    const result = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1', [email]);
    if (result.rows.length > 0) {
      return result.rows[0];
    } else {
      return null; // No user found with that email
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error executing query', err.stack);
    return null;
  }
}

async function getUserById(id) {
  try {
    const result = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [id]);
    if (result.rows.length > 0) {
      return result.rows[0]; // Found user by ID
    } else {
      return null; // No user found with that ID
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error executing query', err.stack);
    return null;
  }
}
// user retrieval from a PostgreSQL database end

//Defining migrate cart items

async function migrateCartItems(sessionId, userId) {
  await pool.query(`
    UPDATE cart SET user_id = $2, session_id = NULL
    WHERE session_id = $1 AND user_id IS NULL
  `, [sessionId, userId]);
  // Handle merging conflicts here if necessary
}

//Defining migrate cart items end


//  A simple query to test the connection and query execution in server.js:
pool.query('SELECT * FROM users', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    console.log(results.rows);
});
//end


//Bcrypt Start 

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);

    // Store user in the database with the hashed password
    const newUser = await pool.query(
      'INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *',
      [username, email, hashedPassword]
    );

    const userId = newUser.rows[0].id; // Get the ID of the newly registered user.
    const sessionId = req.session.id; // Get the session ID of the guest user.

    // Migrate any session cart items to the new user ID.
    await migrateCartItems(sessionId, userId);

    // Automatically log in the new user after registration.
    req.login(newUser.rows[0], err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error during auto-login after registration:', err);
        return res.redirect('/login');
      }
      // Redirect to the home page or cart page after registration and login.
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during registration:', error);
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});

//Bcrypt End

//passport login

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
  failureRedirect: "/login",
  failureFlash: true // Enable flash messages for login failures
}), async (req, res) => {
  const sessionId = req.session.id;
  const userId = req.user.id;

  try {
    // Migrate any session cart items to the user ID.
    await migrateCartItems(sessionId, userId);
    
    // Redirect to the home page or cart page after login.
    res.redirect('/'); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error migrating cart items on login:', error);
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});

//passport login End

//add item to cart

app.post('/add-to-cart', async (req, res) => {
  const { productId, quantity } = req.body;
  const sessionId = req.session.id; // Use the session ID from express-session
  const userId = req.user ? req.user.id : null;

  // Convert productId to an integer if it's a string
  const productIdInt = parseInt(productId, 10);
  

  try {
    // Choose the ON CONFLICT clause based on whether userId is not null
    const onConflictClause = userId 
      ? 'ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT cart_user_product_idx DO UPDATE SET quantity = cart.quantity + EXCLUDED.quantity'
      : 'ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT cart_session_product_idx DO UPDATE SET quantity = cart.quantity + EXCLUDED.quantity';


    const addOrUpdateItem = await pool.query(`
      INSERT INTO cart (user_id, product_id, quantity, session_id)
      VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
      ${onConflictClause}
    `, [userId, productIdInt, quantity, sessionId]);

    res.json({ message: 'Item added to cart successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error adding item to cart:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error adding item to cart' });
  }
});
app.post('/remove-from-cart', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Request to remove from cart:', req.body);
  const itemId = parseInt(req.body.itemId);
  console.log(`Parsed item ID: ${itemId}`);
  const userId = req.user ? req.user.id : null; // to track user ID

  // Check if the parsing resulted in a valid integer
  if (isNaN(itemId)) {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: 'Invalid item ID' });
  }

  // Remove the item from the cart in the database
  try {
    await pool.query('DELETE FROM cart WHERE id = $1 AND (user_id = $2 OR user_id IS NULL)', [itemId, userId]);
    console.log(`Deletion query executed for item ID ${itemId}`);
    res.json({ success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error removing item from cart:', error);
    res.json({ success: false, error: 'Error removing item from cart' });
  }
});


//add item to cart end


//app.listen(3000) //Replace below to get rid of debugging feature. 

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000"); //this is for debugging, lets me know the server is working. 
  });
```

```
// This event listener toggles the dropdown menu for the bars icon
document.getElementById('bars-icon').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation(); // Stop the click from propagating
  var dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');
  dropdown.style.display = dropdown.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
});

// This function closes the dropdown menu if clicked outside
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('#bars-icon')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu");
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.style.display === "block") {
        openDropdown.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
};
function addToCart(productId, quantity) {
  console.log('Adding to cart', productId, quantity);
  fetch('/add-to-cart', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ productId, quantity }),
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
      console.log('Success:', data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
  });
};
function removeFromCart(buttonElement) {
  console.log(buttonElement);
  var itemId = buttonElement.getAttribute('data-item-id'); // Make sure this is an integer
  console.log('Item ID to remove:', itemId);

  itemId = parseInt(itemId, 10);
  console.log('Parsed Item ID:', itemId);

  if (!itemId) {
    // If itemId is not valid (NaN), handle the error.
    alert('Invalid item ID.');
    return;
  }

  // Make a request to your server to remove the item
  fetch('/remove-from-cart', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ itemId: itemId })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (data.success) {
      // If the server responds that the item was removed, update the UI accordingly
      buttonElement.closest('.shopping-cart-item').remove();
      // Update the subtotal, tax, and total elements in your page
      updateSummary();
    } else {
      // Handle failure
      alert('Failed to remove item from cart.');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error removing item from cart:', error);
    alert('There was a problem removing the item from the cart.');
  });
};
function updateSummary() {
  // Define variables for subtotal, taxRate, and total
  let subtotal = 0;
  let taxRate = 0.06; // Example tax rate
  let total;

  // Get all the item prices from the UI and sum them to calculate the new subtotal
  document.querySelectorAll('.item-price').forEach(function(priceElement) {
    let price = parseFloat(priceElement.textContent.replace('Price: $', ''));
    subtotal += price;
  });

  // Calculate the new tax and total
  let taxAmount = subtotal * taxRate;
  total = subtotal + taxAmount;

  // Update the UI elements with the new values
  document.querySelector('.subtotal').textContent = 'Subtotal: $' + subtotal.toFixed(2);
  document.querySelector('.tax').textContent = 'Tax: $' + taxAmount.toFixed(2);
  document.querySelector('.total').textContent = 'Total: $' + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

I tried setting up console.log's to catch my errors and to help me pinpoint exactly where the error is. I keep getting back that the item ID is null. I've been working on this for a while now and feel I may just have tunnel vision and am missing something simple. Or I could be completely wrong in how I set this up. I just recently started working on learning and practicing the backend side of website building. So I apologize if my code is incorrect and looks like a noob wrote it. That because a noob did.

Comment: 1) `Postgresql pgadmin 4` is not a database. There is the Postgres server that you can create a database in and  there is  pgAdmin4 which one of many clients available to connect to a database on the server. 2) At what part of the code are you getting *I keep getting back that the item ID is null*?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm pretty new to the backend and databases. So I am sorry if I stumble through things. That seems to be linked to my script.js file which is the third page. When I remove this line  
if (!itemId) {
    // If itemId is not valid (NaN), handle the error.
    alert('Invalid item ID.');
    return;
  }
I am able to see that it returns item.id = null.

Comment: 1) Is there a valid value for `itemId` in the `console.log()`'s above that line? Or in the `removeFromCart()` code? 2) Are the items actually being added to the database  table? In other words have you checked the data in the table via say `pgAdmin4`.

Comment: yes the items are being added to database table "cart" with the correct product_id, quantity, and a session_id. When it is added the database creates a unique id in the column labeled id [PK] (integer).

Comment: The issue seems that the unique id that is being created when my items are being added to the cart table. Isn't being used by the remove button through the back end logic (script.js and server.js) I believe and could be wrong its related to this on my server.js file (2nd page) 
 // Fetch cart items for a guest user
      const result = await pool.query(`
        SELECT p.*, c.quantity FROM products p
        JOIN cart c ON p.product_id = c.product_id
        WHERE c.session_id = $1
      `, [sessionId]);
      cartItems = result.rows;
    }

Comment: The way to find out is test the query in another client. I would suggest The client that ships with Postgres [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). Verify that the data is going in like you planned and that you can retrieve it as planned.

Comment: Thank you I figured out the issue was that line 
// Fetch cart items for a guest user const result = await pool.query(` SELECT p.*, c.quantity FROM products p JOIN cart c ON p.product_id = c.product_id WHERE c.session_id = $1 `, [sessionId]); cartItems = result.rows; }
I had to modify it a bit to call to the right table. I appreciate your help and time. Thank you!